# Make "x identical lines skipped" expandable

Tags: feature-request, markdown, edits, revisions-list

Recently, I saw this revision:

[image]

I'm using the side-by-side markdown layout to see revisions. Now, I wanted to see the rest of the code to see what impact this revision had. So I think, let's click on "20 identical lines skipped", and the lines will be expanded. But no... I had to use the side-by-side layout - poor me.

Could you make the "x identical lines skipped" expandable (by clicking, for example), so that we can see the whole post, also in the side-by-side markdown layout?

Comment: Every time I click on the bar and it doesn't expand I think exactly the same thing

Comment: This! Please this!

Comment: There are only about 20 pixels between that line and the "inline" and "side-by-side" layouts that would show the information you sought... Is temporarily using those so difficult?

Comment: @C.B. I prefer the markdown layout, sometimes you miss things when not using that one. Would it be so difficult to be able to expand it?

Comment: @CamilStaps : Did you ever design new features in existing apps? Quite a number of scenarios and test cases will have to be created, passed, and maintained for an insignificant feature that offers nothing more over a short-term switch of layout...